# Switch form on submit - jQuery (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form to add item to favorites, and also to delete it.

Let's say this is form for adding and deleting:

```
@if($checkIfFavIsAdded == 0)
    {!! Form::open(['id' => 'ajax-form-add', 'style' => 'float:right']) !!}
      ...
    <button class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" id="addFavbutton" title="Add item to favorites" style="color:#fd8809"></button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open(['id' => 'ajax-form-delete', 'style' => 'float:right']) !!}
      ...
    <button class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" id="addFavbutton" title="Delete item from favorites" style="color:grey"></button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

Here, I am checking if the item is added to favorites, and if so, the appropriate form should be shown.
It works on page reload, but how can I do this in Ajax?
I've tried to hide and show but without success. It just hides the form and don't display another one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ajax-form-add").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('addFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#ajax-form-add").hide();
            $("#ajax-form-delete").show();
        },
        error: function(data){
            swal("Error!", "error")
        },
        complete: function (data) {
     }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#ajax-form-delete").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{{ url('deleteFavorites') }}",
          dataType: "json",
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(data){

              $("#ajax-form-delete").hide();
              $("#ajax-form-show").show();
          },
          error: function(data){
              swal("Error!", "Item is not available!", "error")
          }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Blade templates are rendered server side, what you're trying to do is client side.

If you have that conditional in your blade template, the markup that gets rendered and sent to the browser will not include the other form.

You'll need to return the markup you want to display (IE the new form) in the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

For the second ajax you have written:

```
$("#ajax-form-show").show();
```

No, id with `ajax-form-show` is present. It should be:

```
$("#ajax-form-add").show();
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But it doesn't change anything. It still doesn't show another form. I'm following @Joe's comment and try to include both forms in if and else statement, but first one should be visible and the other one hidden (and vice-versa). Or try to render another form in ajax response.

Comment: @harunB10 The real problem is that you are wring the form inside if and else condition. When the page is rendered, then only 1 form will be there and if you run the ajax, since the second form is missing, it will not show anything. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Now I'm trying to show add form and set visibility to hidden for delete form when `@if($checkIfFavIsAdded == 0)`.